# Bind knockoutjs grid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am new to knockoutjs, I have developed following code to bind knockoutjs grid.

AJAX Function returns JSON but it is not binded grid.

```
var PagedGridModel = function (items) {

    var self = this;

    self.DoctorId = ko.observable();
    self.items = ko.observableArray(items);

    BindPatientGrid(
        function (data, status, xhr) {
            self.items = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(self.items);
        },
        function (Error, status, xhr) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    )

    this.gridViewModel = new ko.simpleGrid.viewModel({
        data: self.items,
        columns: [
        { headerText: "Item Name", rowText: "Name" },
        { headerText: "Sales Count", rowText: "Row" }
        ],
        pageSize: 2
    });

};

ko.applyBindings(new PagedGridModel());

function BindPatientGrid(handleSuccess, handleFailure) {
    var url = '/Index/GetDashboardPatient';
    data = [];
    AjaxGet(url, data, handleSuccess, handleFailure);
}
```

When i try to statically bind JSON in `this.gridViewModel` then it is working properly,AJAX function returns JSON though dynamically with database it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made mistake in assigning array

It worked

```
self.items(JSON.parse(data));
```